# pyplot generates two different graphs?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, matplotlib

I am trying to solve the wave equation using the central finite difference method. 
I started with a basic 2 dimensional Gaussian function as my initial condition `u[x,y,t] =  u[:,:,0] = init_fn(x,y)`

Here my initialization of a Gaussian wave pulse:

```
def init_fn(x,y):
  return A*(np.exp(-1*((x**2)/stdx**2 + (y**2)/stdy**2)))
```

And here is my entire code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.animation as animation

dx=1 #space incrementB  
dy=1
dt=.5 #time increment   #Make sure time increment is smaller than space increment
tmin=0.0 #initial time
tmax=50.0 #simulate until
xmin=-50.0 #left bound
xmax=50.0 #right bound...assume packet never reaches boundary
ymin = -50
ymax = 50

c = 1.0 #speed of sound
rsq1=(c*dt/dx)**2 #appears in finite diff sol for damped and linear damped
rsq2=(c*dt/dy)**2
k = .1
z = 1/(1+ 2*k*dt) #appears in finite diff sol for linear damped 
A = 10

nx = int((xmax-xmin)/dx)+1  #number of points on x grid
ny = int((ymax-ymin)/dy)+1 
nt = int((tmax-tmin)/dt)+2  #number of points on t grid
u = np.zeros((nx,ny,nt)) #solution to WE
stdx = 20
stdy = 20

 #set initial pulse shape
def init_fn(x,y):
 return A*(np.exp(-1*((x**2)/stdx**2 + (y**2)/stdy**2)))  


for j in range(0,nx):
    for m in range (0,ny):
        u[j,m,0]=init_fn(xmin + j*dx,ymin + m*dy)   
        u[j,m,1]=u[j,m,0]


for n in range (1,nt-1):
    for j in range(1,nx-1):
        for m in range (1,ny-1):
            u[j,m,n+1] = rsq1*z*(u[j+1,m,n] + u[j-1,m,n]) + rsq2*z*(u[j,m+1,n]+u[j,m-1,n]) - 2*z*   (rsq1+rsq2+1)*u[j,m,n] - z*(1-2*k*dt)*u[j,m,n-1]

x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = u[:,:,0] #init_fn(xx,yy)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.pcolor(xx, yy, z, cmap=cm.RdBu, vmin=abs(z).min(), vmax=abs(z).max())
cb = fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)

 plt.show()

print u[:,:,0], len(x)
```

It makes logical sense that I should be able to generate the same graph if I graph `u[:,:,0]` and `init_fn(x,y)` since I set them equal to each other. However, the output is different. Setting `z = u[:,:,0]` I get the following output:

[image]

Setting `z = init_fn(xx,yy)` I get the following output:
[image]

Where did I make a mistake in my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is not within `matplotlib`, but somewhere in your loop

```
for j in range(0,nx):
    for m in range (0,ny):
        u[j,m,0]=init_fn(xmin + j*dx,ymin + m*dy)   
        u[j,m,1]=u[j,m,0]
```

Your function `init_fn` consists of `numpy` functions, so you can use `numpy` arrays as input as well. That also speeds up the calculation:

```
# as init_fn is defined with numpy functions,
# you can directly call it with your meshgrid
# to initialize the array u[:,:,0] and u[:,:,1]
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

u[:,:,0] = init_fn(xx,yy)
u[:,:,1] = init_fn(xx,yy)
```

Doing so will yield the expected result.

So it seems you have the problem in your loop where you use the `init_fn()` function. I did check that the x,y values you create in the loop are the same values you have in the meshgrid, so I'm lost where the error lies, but replacing the loop by calling `init_fn(xx,yy)` with the meshgrid avoids the problem!